# How to maintain MVC pattern in QT

Tags: c++, qt4, qt5

I have to create one application in QT using MVC.So, how to maintain a MVC pattern in qt application.How to create a controller in QT ?

Any help ?

Answer (score 2):

MVC means separated model-view-control layers. If you can do, put each layer classes into their own library.

The controller layer is a glue between model and view layers. In it's simplest form, it just connects their signal and slots. More complex controllers are using lambda functions and doing more in their methods.

Comment: Thanks for answer, but you have any simple example that demonstrate separation of model,view and the controller.

Comment: @snehal Not at the moment. When I find time, I'll put example

Comment: Why a shared library? Could it be a static library too?

Comment: @Korchkidu I guess it can be a static library as well